# How to convert Numpy Array into Keras ImageDataGenerator?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

In Kaggle I was given the input data folders.

```
#Training data
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        rotation_range=10,
        zoom_range=0.4,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        validation_split=0.01
        )

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        '../input/chest-xray-covid19-pneumonia/Data/train',
        target_size=(256, 256),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical',
        subset='training'
        )
```

I had to add some more images to this dataset. Hence I converted my **train_generator** to a NumPy (nd) array using this code.

```
x_train=np.concatenate([train_generator.next()[0] for i in range(train_generator.__len__())])
y_train=np.concatenate([train_generator.next()[1] for i in range(train_generator.__len__())])
```

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61039337/how-convert-keras-imagedatagenerator-into-numpy-array)

Now I have concatenated some more images to these image array

```
gan_images = np.concatenate((x_train,t_x), axis=0)
gan_labels = np.concatenate((y_train,t_y), axis=0)
```

Now how can I again convert back it to the **train_generator** format?

```
Type of train_generator is keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator
```

---

**EDIT**

As per suggestion, I tried

```
train_dataset = train_datagen.flow(x_train,y_train)
additional_gan_dataset = train_datagen.flow(t_x,t_y)
abc = np.concatenate((gan_dataset,train_dataset), axis=0)
```

**OOM error in kaggle;**

**Another way I tried**

```
dataset = train_datagen.flow(gan_images, gan_labels)

 history1 = model1.fit(dataset,validation_data=val_generator, verbose=1, epochs= 500,
                       callbacks=[early_stopping, reduce_lr , learning_rate_reduction]
                        )
```

It is working, but here accuracy is coming so poor, I am sure it has not properly merged. I had a total of 5094 images. I have created another 100 images. As these are prefetch datasets I am unable to understand by checking the length. `len(train_dataset) is giving me 160` After merging it is giving me 163. How to fix these? How to understand properly with these prefetch datasets?

Comment: Your code is incorrect, it should be dataset = train_datagen.flow(gan_images, gan_labels)

Answer (score 2):

[`ImageDataGenerator.flow(x_array, y_array)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow)

```
dataset = ImageDataGenerator.flow(gan_images, gan_labels)
```

Although, unless you need the methods of ImageDataGenerator or really need a dataset object, you can just pass the arrays to `.fit()`.

Comment: Hi @Djinn , I need to apply here.                                                                                                          
                       history = model3.fit(train_generator,
                              validation_data=val_generator, verbose=1, epochs= 500,
                       callbacks=[early_stopping, reduce_lr , learning_rate_reduction]
                        )
    Hence looking for this. I have applied the way you have told me. let's see.

Comment: If that's all you need, with no processing on the dataset after creating it, you still don't necessarily need to convert it to a dataset object. That's just extra overhead. But you could also add images directly to the dataset too, I believe, without needing to convert to arrays.

Comment: I tried a LOT. I generated the images using GAN. Unfortunately, I am not able to add those to the kaggle training set folder directly. Hence this approach!

Comment: Place the new images in a dataset, then use `dataset.concatenate(additional_dataset)`

Comment: Also to convert dataset to array, use `dataset.as_numpy_iterator()`

Comment: I am getting new images as image (NumPy) array and labels array. How could I make additional_dataset.  kindly check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73859157/how-to-save-ac-gan-generated-images-with-3-labels-as-folder?noredirect=1#comment130417580_73859157

Comment: Using the answer I provided.

Comment: ImageDataGenerator is not an object, it's a class, one with an object that you didn't initialize. Follow whatever guide you're following to create your datagens and try to match with the answer. It's exactly like what's in your question.