# Question about datagen.flow_from_directory casting the images in tensor float32

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I saw that using datagen.flow_from_directory the images were in numpy, and I wanted to convert them to tf tensor float 32 for faster simulation.
I tried the below code which generated by chatgpt but errors occured, I know is a stupid, question but could someone help me to resolve this?

thank you in advance
[image]

Comment: You can use this code as given in the article from [medium](https://vijayabhaskar96.medium.com/tutorial-image-classification-with-keras-flow-from-directory-and-generators-95f75ebe5720) to convert your numpy image to a tensorflow array. Another stackoverflow [conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73886825/how-to-convert-numpy-array-into-keras-imagedatagenerator) also has resolved the same difficulty.